# jquery .animate() in a loop using the index on complete:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that runs multiple animations at once, and based on when a new animation starts, the rest of the elements currently animating have to .stop() and move to another loation (this is working). So I built an array of animations that gets .animate()'ed when a new animation is added, and when each animation completes I need to remove it from the array. Here is the code I tried using:

```
for (var i = 0; i < animations[key].length; i++) {
animations[key][i].object.animate({
    top: animations[key][i].endCoords.top,
    left: animations[key][i].endCoords.left
}, {
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
        console.log(i);
        animations[key].splice(i, 1);
        console.log(animations);
    }
});
}
```

The problem is when complete: runs, `i` is set to animations[key].length. I am pretty sure I  understand why it is doing that, because the for loop is continuing before the animation is finished (which is good because it does allow me to run multiple animations at once), but is there any way to write the code so that when complete: runs it has the right index to do the splice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using/allocating a different variable for each iteration should do:

```
for (var i = animations[key].length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var id = i;
    animations[key][id].object.animate({
        top: animations[key][id].endCoords.top,
        left: animations[key][id].endCoords.left
    }, {
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
            console.log(id);
            animations[key].splice(id, 1);
            console.log(animations);
        }
    });
}
```

otherwise you'll end up calling `animations[key].splice(animations[key].length, 1)` every time (because the loop executes before any animation has time to complete).

Even so, you might want to reconsider your approach: unless animations complete in the exact same order they started in, you might still have troubles!

*edit:* inverted the loop direction (see note below) - this has the side effect of starting animations in reverse order

Comment: This solutions works when there is just one item in the array, but when there are multiple the same issue happens, they all end up having the same value. What would you recommend i do to "reconsider my approach"?

Comment: Oh - gosh! If animations end in order, I end up calling splice(0,1) - which moves all elements one index down - then splice(1,1) - which actually removes the element which originally had index 2 - then splice(3,1) - which removes the original element 5 - and so on... the iteration should go the other side (from .length downwards). Sorry for not spotting this earlier

Comment: As for the "approach" thing, I don't really know enough of what your intention are to recommend anything... unless you really need animations[key] to stay "full" until animations are _complete_, you could just pop animations out of the queue first and then run them – otherwise you could consider using a different data structure than an array for holing animations (a linked list would allow removing elements without messing up indexes - a map/dictionary could be even simpler to handle)... it really depends on what you need to do (besides starting animations)

Comment: I think I will try those options out. Thanks for the input!